# Python : download as pdf all emails from a label (gmail)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, download, gmail-api

I would like to download 100+ email from gmail as pdf. It would be too long to manually download all of them via the print option in gmail.

This python script retrieves the emails in the chosen label. How can I convert this email into a pdf.

```
# source  = https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?authuser=2

from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request



SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API 

    response= service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds="Label_53", q=None, pageToken=None, maxResults=None, includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
    all_message_in_label = []
    if 'messages' in response:
        all_message_in_label.extend(response['messages'])

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds="Label_53", q=None, pageToken=page_token, maxResults=None, includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
      all_message_in_label.extend(response['messages'])


    if not all_message_in_label:
        print('No email LM found.')
    else:
        # get message from Id listed in all_message_in_label
        for emails in all_message_in_label: 
            message= service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=emails["id"], format="raw", metadataHeaders=None).execute()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little bit of digging about your problem and I found a few links that could be of use:

**On converting your messages to `.eml` format [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524667/how-to-save-gmail-as-eml-file-using-gmail-api-and-chrome-extension) link.**

**On converting from `.eml` to `.pdf` these links:**

[eml2pdf](https://github.com/andrewferrier/email2pdf) is a python github project which converts `eml` files to `pdf` but Im not sure if it is working or not. You could check it out to see if it works.

[eml-to-pdf](https://github.com/BramEsposito/eml-to-pdf) is another github project which seems inferior yet working. its written in javascript.

and there is [pyPdf](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf) which you can use to generate `pdf` files. though with this you might need to convert the e-mails and format them yourself.

for more information on message objects formatting you can refer to gmail api python docs [get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get) method.

**And [here](http://pixelcog.com/blog/2015/gmail-to-pdf/) is a blog post which does what you are looking for using a different approach** though I am not entirely sure if it still works.

I hope it helps. good luck.

Comment: thanks, for showing me the right track! And yes, gmail-to-pdf (the blog post) is still working but not for all emails (cf the issue on github) and not for nested labels and only for starred email (the last 2 drawbacks require only a simple fix).

Comment: I am glad it was helpful. @MagTun

Answer (score 3):

I tried the recommendations from Ali Nuri Seker answer but they didn't work :
- eml2pdf: not working on Windows
- eml-to-pdf: error in Mime Type
- pyPdf: too much work as you need to build the whole design
- gmail-to-pdf: bug in code for some emails (cf the bug is mentioned on github)

What worked (same general idea than Ali Nuri Seker):

1. save the emails as .eml with  `email.generator.Generator`
2. Use [eml-to-pdf-converter](https://github.com/nickrussler/eml-to-pdf-converter)  (not python based but open source GUI) to convert the .eml file to pdf  (you basically just drop the folder containing your .eml files, click on a button, and you get your pdf. It even works with sub-folders!)

---

More detailled scripts can be found [here](https://github.com/MagTun/gmail-to-pdf)

---

This is the first script "save email as .eml":

```
# source  = https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?authuser=2

# In brief:
# this script will connect to your gmail account and download as .eml file your email from a specified label. 
# then you can convert the .eml files to pdf :  https://github.com/nickrussler/eml-to-pdf-converter

# set up
#  1) save this script in a folder
#  2) save the script "get labels id.py" in the same folder
#  3) go to this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python and click on "Enable the gmail API", then click on "Download client configuration" and save this .json file in the same folder as this script
#  4) GMAIL API doesn't use Label name but ID so you need to run the script "get labels id.py" and to copy the ID for the label you need (the firt time, you will be ask the persmission on  a consent screen, accept it with the account where you want to download your email)  
#  5) copy your label id below in custom var 
#  6) run this script and your emails will be saved as .eml file in a subfolder "emails as eml"

# connect to gmail api 
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# decode response from Gmail api and save a email
import base64
import email

#for working dir and path for saving file
import os

# CUSTOM VAR 
labelid = "Label_18"  # change your label id

# set working directory  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432949/3154274
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
print("working dir set to ", dname)

# create folder to save email 
emailfolder= dname+"\emails as eml"
if not os.path.exists(emailfolder):
    os.makedirs(emailfolder)


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():

    # create the credential the first tim and save then in token.pickle
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    #create the service 
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)


    # get the *list* of all emails in the labels (if there are multiple pages, navigate to them)
    #*************************************
    #  ressources for *list* email by labels
    # https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/index.html 
    # https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#list
    # example of code for list: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22includeSpamTrash%22%3Afalse%2C%22labelIds%22%3A%5B%22LM%22%5D%7D
    #*************************************

    response= service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds=labelid, q=None, pageToken=None, maxResults=None, includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
    all_message_in_label = []
    if 'messages' in response:
        all_message_in_label.extend(response['messages'])

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds=labelid, q=None, pageToken=page_token, maxResults=None, includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
      all_message_in_label.extend(response['messages'])


    # all_message_in_label looks like this 
            # for email in all_message_in_label:
                # print(email)
                #{'id': '169735e289ba7310', 'threadId': '169735e289ba7310'}
                #{'id': '169735c76a4b93af', 'threadId': '169735c76a4b93af'}    
    if not all_message_in_label:
        print('No email LM found.')
    else:
        # for each ID in all_message_in_label we *get* the message 

        #*************************************
        # ressources for *get* email 
        # https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get
        # code example for decode https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get 
        #  + decode for python 3 https://python-forum.io/Thread-TypeError-initial-value-must-be-str-or-None-not-bytes--12161
        #*************************************

        for emails in all_message_in_label: 
            message= service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=emails["id"], format="raw", metadataHeaders=None).execute()
            msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

            try: 
                mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str.decode())  

                # the the message as a .eml file 
                outfile_name = os.path.join(emailfolder, f'{emails["id"]}.eml')

                with open(outfile_name, 'w') as outfile:
                    gen = email.generator.Generator(outfile)
                    gen.flatten(mime_msg)
                print("mail saved: ", emails["id"])

            except:
                print("error in message ", message["snippet"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the second script "get labels ids.py" (cf "Set up" step 4. in first script)

```
# source  = https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?authuser=2

from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Get list of all labels
    #  https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/index.html
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label['name'] + " "+label['id'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    input("continue")
```